# Oracle Query Help

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
  ID          Date
  1   08/10/2009 11:20:00
  2   08/10/2009 12:06:06
  3   08/11/2009 13:03:10
  4   08/11/2009 01:20:00
  5   08/11/2009 15:41:23
  6   08/12/2009 14:22:20
```

I want to return:

```
Date          Count
08/10/2009     2
08/11/2009     3
08/12/2009     1
```

in PL/SQL.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  TRUNC(date) AS CreatedDate, COUNT(*) AS DateCount
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        TRUNC(date)
ORDER BY
        CreatedDate
```

Comment: Doing this in PL/SQL requires creating a cursor from your query. Not very difficult at all.

Comment: +1: you beat me to it, but i would have called it `this_table`.

Comment: I don't understand how count(*) would correspond to the count of those entries that correspond to each distinct date.

Comment: `@Saobi`: `TRUNC(date)` truncates the dates, leaving only the date portions. `GROUP BY TRUNC(date)` makes `COUNT(*)`'s for each group that shares the truncated values of the dates.

Comment: Also, what if i want to display the date column as "CreatedDate" and Sort by that column ?

Comment: `@akf`: that's why I use `mytable`. It's shorter.